# How to decrease the gap between training and validation error?

Tags: deep-learning

I have been executing an open-source Text-to-speech system [Ossian](https://github.com/CSTR-Edinburgh/Ossian). It uses feed forward DNNs for it's acoustic modeling. The error graph I've got after running the acoustic model looks like this:
[image: Plot of training vs. validation error of acoustic modeling]
Here are some relevant information:

- Size of Data: 7 hours of speech data (4000 sentences)
- Some hyper-parameters:

  - batch_size       : 128
  - training_epochs  : 15
  - L2_regularization: 0.003

Can anyone point me to the directions to improve this model? I'm assuming it is suffering from over-fitting problem? What should I do to avoid this? Increasing data? Or changing batch-size/epochs/regularization parameters? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like overfitting. Increasing the amount of training data should help. Increasing the amount of regularisation should help, as well as reducing the complexity of the model. To answer that we need more details about the DNN at use here. About changing the number of epochs, looking into early stoppage, e.g. stopping the training when the validation loss starts increasing.

Answer (score 2):

As *Learning is a mess* points out, more information would help make useful suggestions. What is the size of the model (in terms of the trainable parameters)? Also, how much training data do you have?
However, you can try these: 
a. Dropouts - this a regularization method, it is a kind of proxy for ensemble learning. Not sure if you are using this.
b. Smaller Batches: 8/16/32 - Empirically it has been found that smaller batches find better minimums in the sense of generalization on the test/validation sets. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04836.pdf. 
c. Holding the number of parameters the same, deeper models (more layers) have been found to generalize better. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.10239.